# How to add another noise node to this existing node configuration

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have this node set up, trying to make this Frisbee texture, The material looks to clean. The reference of the Frisbee has a little bit of noise added to it, but I cant get the configuration correct with the send noise node I'm trying to add.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to Jag JB's answer, you might want to consider applying a noise on the INPUT of the noise texture, to bend (distort) the noise rather than mix two noises, as the "Distortion" input doesn't give you that much of a control:

[image]

The **Scale** above should be probably at most 10% of what it is currently, but I wanted to make the effect clearly visible:

[image]

And of course you can mix it together with another noise (as in Jag JB's answer)…

Answer (score 4):

You can Color Mix > Mix (or Overlay) the two noises before your first color ramp.

Just use different scales of noise to create a visible effect.

[image]

Comment: can you please do the configuration of the nodes, thank you.

Comment: Done. And frisbee added also.